# Layout of XML not as well as expected

Tags: android

I have a problem as following
I write a layout by XML Android. Here is my result image. But I want to "Mhz" must be in bottom of this view, not top. I would like to get some helps from someone. Thanks. Here is my code in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="63px"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="26px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
            android:layout_marginTop="2px" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header_news"
                android:layout_width="48px"
                android:layout_height="18px"
                android:src="@drawable/header_icon_news"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header_tp"
                android:layout_width="26px"
                android:layout_height="18px"
                android:src="@drawable/header_icon_tp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/header_news"
                android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />
            <ImageView

                android:id="@+id/header_ta"
                android:layout_width="26px"
                android:layout_height="18px"
                android:src="@drawable/header_icon_ta"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/header_tp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2px" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_tv_1690"
                android:layout_width="60px"
                android:layout_height="30px"
                android:textSize="27px"
                android:text="@string/header_test_chanel" 
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/header_tv_mhz"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"          
                android:textColor="#F0F0F0" 
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header_6"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_width="32px"
                android:layout_height="32px"
                android:src="@drawable/audio_icon_preset06"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/header_tv_1690"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header_station"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_width="32px"
                android:layout_height="32px"
                android:src="@drawable/header_icon_station"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/header_6"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:background="#666666"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/header_fm"
                android:layout_width="96px"
                android:layout_height="32px"
                android:src="@drawable/header_audiotitle_fm"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/header_station"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_tv_mhz"
                android:layout_width="30px"
                android:layout_height="30px"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="@string/header_test_mhz"
                android:textColor="#F0F0F0"
                android:textSize="15px" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can u please give screen shot what u exactly want..

Comment: android:layout_height="63px" in main layout? what is this????

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom" property make it bottom
```